# How to sort entries on NSComboBox when working with an Internal List

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an [NSComboBox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nscombobox_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSComboBox/addItemsWithObjectValues:) and I do not use a data source with it but use the internal list capabilities instead. So I fill it with the `addItemsWithObjectValues` and `addItemWithObjectValue` methods.

My question is how can I sort the combo box entries from my internal list alphabetically after adding something new with `addItemWithObjectValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain a sort in `NSComboBox` without using a data-source. Firstly, when you initially add the items you must sort it like so:

```
// Using NSComparator because it is needed later on
NSComparator sort = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare: obj2];
};

[comboBox addItemsWithObjectValues: [titles sortedArrayUsingComparator: sort]];
```

Next, when you wish to maintain the sorting when you add individual items in:

```
NSArray *objectValues = comboBox.objectValues;
[comboBox insertItemWithObjectValue: newTitle 
                            atIndex: [objectValues indexOfObject: newTitle
                                                   inSortedRange: NSMakeRange(0, objectValues.count) 
                                                         options: NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex 
                                                 usingComparator: sort]];
```

This works by finding the appropriate index to insert the new item and inserting the item at that index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to precalculate where the new items should go in the list and use `- (void)insertItemWithObjectValue:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSInteger)index` to insert them at the appropriate index.

You cannot reorder the internal list. You'd need to use `- (void)removeAllItems` and re-add them again in an ordered fashion.